# Can I have another account after having one account been banned by sock puppet?

Tags: support, account-suspension, sock-puppets

Is it OK to have another account after having one been banned by sock puppet? What could happen if I create other account and follow the site rules?

Comment: Wait...you can get banned *by* a sock puppet? How does that happen?

Comment: Do you mean banned *as a* sock puppet? Only moderators can manually ban people.

Answer (score 14):

Creating a new account to evade a suspension is against the rules, even if you promise to behave on your new account. Do not do it.

I advise you to wait out the suspension (if it's still active), and resume on your original account. As long as you do not repeat the sock puppet offense, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it OK to have another account after having one been banned by sock puppet?

Don't create a new account if your account suspended this is against the rules

**don't do that** *what if your new account is also suspend than  you will create again new account* i think its not a good idea

> What could happen if I create other account and follow the site rules?

Even better idea wait to complete suspension period and follow the site rules with your old account